# SWIFT4. Не могу загрузить данные из Firebase по сотовой сети. Через WiFi всё отлично!

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-database, swift4

Всем привет! Мое приложение отлично работает через wifi, но по сотовой сети никакие данные не грузятся. Месяц назад все работало хорошо, кто-нибудь знает в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Блокировки роскомнадзора?

Comment: @VAndrJ очень может быть